# How is p[a:b:c] handled by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I am trying these in the python shell and am getting quite confusing results.

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
>>> p 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> p[2:8:2]
[3, 5, 7]
>>> id(p[2:8:2])
37798416
>>> id(p[2:8:2])
37798416
>>> id(p[2:8:2])
50868392
```

Note how the id changed the 3rd time !

```
>>> id(p[2:8:2])
37798336
```

And changed again !
Question#1: How and why did that happen ?

Question#2:

```
>>> p[2:8:2] = [33,55,77]
>>> p
[1, 2, 33, 4, 55, 6, 77, 8]
```

How does python exactly "store" p[2:8:2] ? (may be "store" is not the right word, but I hope you get the idea). It does not look like it is a distinct list from the original list (though it is made up of non-sequential immutable items from the original list), as changes to *this* list are reflected in the original list !

Comment: In Qn2, I am not asking about the notation. But about how the (sub) list is created and managed and what does it exactly contain ? Is it a list of references to items in the original list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slicing, with rare exception, makes brand new copies of whatever you're slicing. So all the `id` checks are telling you is that sometimes the new `list` reuses the memory from last time, and sometimes it uses a different bit of memory. The exact behavior is pure implementation detail. In CPython (the reference interpreter) `id` happens to correspond to memory addresses, so all you're seeing is a behavioral artifact of the allocator, not some deep meaning to slicing.

On your question #2: When use in an assignment context, slicing modifies the original sequence, it doesn't create a new `list` at all. Don't try to draw meaningful parallels between slicing (read oriented, makes new sequences) and slice assignment (write oriented, modifies existing sequences); the behaviors under the hood are different in almost every way.

Comment: For the "rare exceptions" I mentioned, think the `memoryview` built-in, and `numpy` arrays, which don't perform shallow copies, but instead make new views of the underlying memory. `id` is even more useless there though, since it will tell you the subslice has a different identity, but in these cases, it actually does share the underlying storage.

Answer (score 1):

***For question 1:***

The id of an object is guaranteed to both be unique and stay constant *during the lifetime of that object.* See [here in the Python library docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id):

> `id(object)` - return the identity of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

Since you're creating and destroying objects with your slicing, the id is actually following the rules.

If you're using the reference (and I suspect most common) implementation, CPython, it simply gives you the memory address of the object. The source code can be found in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c), simplified and annotated below:

```
static PyObject *builtin_id(PyModuleDef *self, PyObject *v) {
    PyObject *id = PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v); // Turn object address into
    return id;                            //    long and return it.
}
```

That ensures that it's unique and the vagaries and order of memory allocation calls also explain why it can repeat and/or be different.

---

***For question 2:***

Assigning to the "slice" does *not* actually involve creating the sliced object and assigning to it. It simply sets certain values in the already existing object as specified by the slice notation to those given on the right hand side of the assignment.

More detail can be found in the `sliceobject` files in the CPython source code, specifically [Objects/sliceobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c) and [Include/sliceobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/sliceobject.h). These involve the creation of a `PySliceObject` which consists of a `{start, stop, step}` tuple.

When you apply this tuple to an object on the right hand side of an assignment, such as `x = y[2:8:2]`, it uses the `PySliceObject` to create a new list `x` based on `y`, getting *only* the relevant elements.

When used on the *left* hand side, such as `x[2:8:2] = [33,55,77]`, it uses the `PySliceObject` to decide which elements of `x` are set to the values on the right.

Comment: Excellent answer with great details ! But I marked the other answer as the Answer as it essentially conveys the same aspects as this one (though with less details) but came in first.